# Jquery attribute selector doesn't work under Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

```
$("div[f3id='vscroller'").each(function () {
.... any code ....
});
```

generates the following error message under Firefox.

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div[f3id='vscroller'
```

Change the code to

```
$('div[f3id="vscroller"')
```

doesn't solve the problem.

Under Chrome it works fine.

I would be thankful for any idea or work-around.

Comment: Missing `]` - `$("div[f3id='vscroller']")`

Comment: I guess it's a typo!

Answer (score -1):

```
$("div[f3id='vscroller']").each(function () {
alert();
});
```

Comment: @Leandro not sure it was a typo as much as the OP doesn't know how to use selectors. I mean if it were a typo, you can see that thing even while standing 10 meters from your monitor...

Comment: @EduardLuca I understand you but "off topic - typo" when a question is flagged as a typo, it means that the question and/or the answer is not useful in the future for anyone, not just a missmatch. In this case, even if the user doesn't know how to write the line, it wont be useful to anyone.

Comment: Can't argue with that.